# How to allow users to search based on two criteria

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uisearchbar

I'm trying to implement a search bar, where the user can search for someone based on their name or their occupation. I wrote the function below, but the app is crashing at the return statement with the OR operator. Is there a proper way to write this function to allow for both possibilities -- getting results based on typing in a person's name OR their occupation? Note: I am using Firebase to store user information; name and occupation have their own separate fields and corresponding values.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            
    if searchText.isEmpty || searchText == " " {
        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        filteredUsers = users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return user.name.contains(searchText) || user.occupation.contains(searchText)
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Look ok to me. What does the crash log/stack trace say?

Comment: What error are you getting....?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value. Not sure what's wrong here, because it works fine when implemented without the OR statement.

Comment: occupation is nil then

Comment: In that case I'd guess that the occupation field is optional in your data structure.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but there's an if let statement for the occupation in the user data structure, so I'm a bit puzzled here.

Comment: if you would share your if let statement that could better

Comment: if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
        }                                                                                              if let occupation = dictionary["occupation"] as? String {
            self.occupation = occupation
        }

Comment: I think I figured it out actually

Comment: I think you set occupation as an optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit your code like this:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) 
{
    if searchText.isEmpty || searchText == " " {
        inSearchMode = false
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        filteredUsers = users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return (user.name?.contains(searchText) ?? true) || (user.occupation?.contains(searchText) ?? true)
        })
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have getting nil value as occupation is optional so you can refactor your function as below:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    
    if searchText.isEmpty || searchText == " " {
        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        filteredUsers = users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            if let occupation = user.occupation {
                return occupation.contains(searchText)
            }
            if let name = user.name {
                return name.contains(searchText)
            }
            return false
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to make sense but throws the following error: Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Bool'

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to prevent the nil error:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            
    if searchText.isEmpty || searchText == " " {
        inSearchMode = false
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        filteredUsers = users.filter({ (user) -> Bool in
            return (user.name.contains(searchText) == true) || (user.occupation.contains(searchText) == true)
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```